# ScreenReader skips all links inside vertical list

Tags: html, accessibility, voiceover, screen-readers

I have an issue with using tab navigation or screen reader.

I have a bunch of divs with list inside of it, where each list item has a link, as shown in example below. This html represents vertical "carousel", where user can vertically scroll across the items.
The entire carousel is shown inside of popover (if it matters at all). And it has a lot of CSS to keep carousel scrollable(`overflow:hidden`, not sure if it matters).

While testing the widget for Accessibility, I found an issue:

Carousel container is not focusable when using tab navigation or screen reader. So, the entire container is just skipped by ScreenReader (Voice Over) and it never goes inside container to read the links.

I tried to add `tabindex="-1"` for the top most div element, and now it receives the focus, however, it doesn't go inside the div to go through the links.

What can be the reasons for that? How can I make VoiceOver not skip the content and go through all the links

```html
<div class="a-carousel-viewport" id="carousel">
    <ol class="carousel" role="list" aria-busy="false">
        <li class="carousel-card" role="listitem" aria-setsize="12" aria-posinset="11" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="item">
                <h4>Title 1</h4>
                <a aria-hidden="true" class="a-link-normal vse-carousel-item" tabindex="-1" href="/someurl">
                    <div class="content">
                    </div>
                </a>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="carousel-card" role="listitem" aria-setsize="12" aria-posinset="11" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="item">
                <h4>Title 2</h4>
                <a aria-hidden="true" class="a-link-normal vse-carousel-item" tabindex="-1" href="/someurl">
                    <div class="content">
                    </div>
                </a>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ol>
</div>
```

Comment: you will need to create a full fiddle rather than just show the HTML. There are loads of things we can't know just be looking at the markup you posted. Does the carousel intercept key presses? Does the carousel remove the `aria-hidden` from the links when a slide is active? Why did you add `tabindex="-1"` rather than `tabindex="0"`? Why do you need a `tabindex` at all to access links? As you can see these are impossible to answer from just the HTML. Create a fiddle that demonstrates the behaviour please and then we can help.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to check the behaviour just from the HTML, a JSfiddle or CodePen to include the JavaScript would help a lot. However, you've got a lot of ARIA attributes that aren't necessary and might be confusing VoiceOver.

The first thing I'd try if you can't provide a demo of the problem behaviour is to remove all of the role and aria-attributes from your code sample and see if that fixes the problem. The roles for list and listitem are redundant on list (ol) and list item (li) elements. aria-setsize and aria-posinset are also not needed on lists. Tabindex and aria-hidden might be needed depending on how the carousel hides slides which aren't visible, but if removing the roles and aria-attributes doesn't help, it might be useful to remove them and see if VoiceOver can find the links when you do.